# Intermittant database error with django and postgres: django sometimes tries to query a database I deleted weeks ago

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I'm building a simple web application in django, using sqlite in development, and running postgres in production.  Everything works fine on my local server, but I've run into a strange error on the production side.

The bug affects several parts of the site, but the clearest example is on the admin page.  Sometimes when I go to inspect entries in the Sentence table, I get this error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/treeLing_app/sentence/

column treeLing_app_sentence.sexp does not exist
LINE 1: ...ce"."comment_id", "treeLing_app_sentence"."text", "treeLing_...
                                                         ^
```

The confusing thing about this is that the sexp (for "s-expression") field was only included in the very early versions of the database design.  There's no trace of it left in the code.  I've also dropped and re-created the development and production databases since then.

Bottom line: I can't figure out how django/postgres even knows about the old sexp field.  On top of that, I don't understand why the error only pops up occasionally.  It seems as though something has gone deeply wrong with the magic that is django's ORM.  Can anyone solve this mystery for me?

A few other details that might be useful:

- When the error occurs, it tends to happen several times in a row -- as if the DB goes into another mode for a few minutes.
- In other parts of the site, the bug manifests differently.  When templates reference fields in sentence objects, the fields are simply blank. I've had a hard time debugging this because the problem only shows up some of the time, and I haven't been able to replicate it on my development machine.
- postgres is version 9.1.1; I'm using psycopg2.
- I'm using South. But as I said earlier, I've completely dropped and recreated both databases--along with all migrations--since the problem began, so I doubt South is the problem.
- I'm running all this on the bitnami djangostack. Not sure why that would make any difference, but you never know...

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**: Some new info: after much testing, I haven't been able to replicate the error on the production server when using django's ./manage.py runserver command -- the error only seems to happen when using the apache/wsgi server.

This seems to narrow down the problem.  Any suggestions for tracking it down further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is silly -- restart apache and postgresql.  What a day.

Answer (score 0):

If all the South migrations have been applied successfully (you didn't --fake any of them, did you?), I guess it's possible you have a compiled .pyc file left over from the older state of the models. Try the following at the project root:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

Comment: I did --fake one of the migrations on the production side.  But that was after completely wiping both (dev and prod) databases.